# binding server socket to port fails (C)

Tags: c, sockets, bind

My code will always proc the "Binding Failure" error and I do not know why. I have read the man page multiple times and I can't find anything wrong with the code, can someone please steer me in the right direction?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    #define PORT 3490
    #define BACKLOG 10

    int main()
    {
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct sockaddr_in dest;
        int status,socket_fd, client_fd,num;
        socklen_t size;

        char buffer[10241];
        char *buff;
    //  memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        int yes =1;



        if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Socket failure!!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
        memset(&dest,0,sizeof(dest));
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
        if ((bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr )))== -1)    { //sizeof(struct sockaddr) 
            fprintf(stderr, "Binding Failure\n");


      exit(1);
//other irrelevant code starts here
```

Comment: When you get an error, call `perror()`. Don't just print something vague of your own devising. Please fix that and edit the result into your question.

Comment: this is a very strange buffer size and such a large buffer probably should be in file scope rather than on the stack

Comment: this line: 'int yes =1;' should probably be a const

Comment: if, instead of this line: 'fprintf(stderr, "Binding Failure\n");' an informative function were to be used, for instance 'perror()' then the actual system error message would be displayed on stderr

Comment: Nit pick - you should pass `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` as the third parameter to your `bind()` call. but that's not your bug.

Answer (score 2):

If `netstat -an|grep 3490` really shows 127.0.0.1 you have another process listening at the port, bound to 127.0.0.1 instead of INADDR_ANY, which is why the SO_REUSEADDR didn't work. But you will *never* know for sure until you take my advice above.

Answer (score 0):

After using perror, I found that the address was taken and I switched to another port and it worked!